# Show image in my Prototype Cells xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

Good afternoon,

I'm having problems showing an image in my Prototype Cells. At the moment I can only show a label text and I would like to know what I have to do to show an image.

Here is an screenshot of the current process:

I have a URL of the image but at the moment is only showing it as a label:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8l5t.png

I would like to show that as an image. What I have to do to achieve that?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Retrieve cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Get the location to be shown
    Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel.text = item.address;

    return myCell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you haven't even *tried* to add an image here... You can either add an image as a subview or use the cell's image property.

Comment: I have added a imageView in my MainStoryBoard.

Comment: But in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you're only setting your cell's text label property...  Is `item.address` the image's web url?

Comment: Yes, the item.address is the image url path. How can I set the image property for my cell? Thanks Lyndsey.

Comment: The image url is in a website, full url path. Thanks.

Comment: myCell.imageView.imageURL = [NSURL urlWithString:item.address]; would work but before this add https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView into your project and import AsyncImageView.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UITableView`'s `imageView` object as opposed to the `UITableView`'s `UILabel` object. For example, replace:

```
myCell.textLabel.text = item.address;
```

with:

```
myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.address]]];
```

Or you can customize the image view by adding a `UIImageView` as a subview instead.

Comment: I get the following error: /Users/Downloads/DatabaseTableViewApp 3/DatabaseTableViewApp/ViewController.m:92:83: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSURL *'
Thanks.

Comment: @JulienKP Oh, then if your address is formatted as an NSString, you'll have to change it to an NSUrl. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before `return myCell` set the cell's image property. For example, if you have an array of images called "images" corresponding to your cells you could do something like this:

```
myCell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
```

You could also create your own prototype cell by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and setting the class of the prototype cell in the tableview to be your own subclass. You can then add your own `UIImageView` wherever you want in the prototype cell and create an `IBOutlet` which links to your custom cell class. Your method could then look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Retrieve cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    MyCustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Get the location to be shown
    Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

    // Get references to labels of cell
    customCell.customLabel.text = item.address;

    customCell.customImageView.image = arrayOfImages[indexPath.row]

    return customCell;
}
```